# Where did the current flurry of new and novice users come from?

Tags: discussion, new-users

In the last 12 hours or so there have been a [bunch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10344/472) [of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10349/472) [questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10348/472) from new users, many seemingly based on non-Jewish perspectives and/or translations.  Where did they come from, and should we be doing anything to try to re-orient their questions?  I don't want to be unwelcoming to people who are truly interested in *Jewish* topics, but I'm having trouble telling when that's the case with some of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, and I think allowing too many of these questions to go unchecked could be potentially very damaging, particularly right now at a time that many Jews are probably searching for information about High Holidays.  If they do the right search, they could land on this site and find some great information.  Then, when they check out the front page, they will be instantly turned off by the non-Jewish perspective, quoting from non-Jewish translations, and poor grammar of whoever is doing this.

Personally, I think each of us, and particularly those with editing privileges, should be closing and down-voting the most egregiously non-constructive questions and making a best-faith effort to transform the salvageable questions into something this site could be proud of.

Comment: I hope they go away today, or we may have A LOT of cleanup work after Shabbos.

Comment: I do agree with this, but I am noticing that many are being closed when they could be salvaged. A the very least, in these cases there could be some standard response; e.g. an explanation that this is a _Jewish_ site and a link to an accurate translation/interpretation of the source.

Comment: @HodofHod, closure is not permanent. It can always come off if a question is improved sufficiently, and it does not disable either editing or commenting, so people can pitch in and try to make the improvements if they're so inclined.

Comment: I did see cleanup happen on some of them, getting rid of "old testament" references and removing some snarky comments.  The timing is unfortunate. :-(

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I don't think there is a flurry of new and novice users at all… rather, I think that there's one user with an agenda who set up ten accounts (user ids 915-917 and 919-925, for anyone keeping track).

I've merged them all into one, and I'll continue to keep an eye on him.

Comment: Ah, that would explain the cluster of such questions.

Comment: Isn't that against some terms or something? If he's doing tricks like that, there's no reason to fix or respond to such questions, they should just be closed.

Comment: & 937 for the record.