# For how long should a closed question be allowed to appear?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Related to the question on the [current flurry of novice users](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/where-did-the-current-flurry-of-new-and-novice-users-come-from) what is and what should be the period of time that a closed question can still appear on the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A closed question is just that: a question that was closed. Closed questions do not always represent bad (especially in the case of a duplicate). In some cases it's a good thing to have closed questions stick around.

With that being said, here's how the deletion process works:

**48 hours** after a question is closed it is eligible to be voted for deletion by anyone with the [moderator tools privilege](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) [1,000 rep in beta, and 10,000 rep afterwards]. [Trusted users](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user) [2,000 rep in beta and 20,000 afterwards], on the other hand, can vote to delete immediately after a question is closed.

Once a post gets 3 votes to delete, it is deleted. However, note that even deleted questions can be visible by ["moderator tool" users](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) - which includes you!

Additionally, anyone can delete their own questions (I believe after 24 hours).

Also note: Moderators (people with the diamond) can delete a question at any time. If you really feel a question should be deleted, give one of them a call for help by **flagging** the question.

Answer (score 3):

A closed question can be seen indefinitely. I doubt that that's going to change, although I suppose one of the Stack Exchange employees can speak with more certainty to that question.

It is also possible to delete a question, but being of poor quality is not usually enough of a reason. See [the deletion section of the FAQ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion).